# Path to images not referenced correctly inside custom blocks

Tags: theming, 8

Let me get right into the code to demonstrate the problem.

I have created a custom block layout in `/admin/structure/block/block-content` with the following html content.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
     <img src="/themes/mytheme/images/flag.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, this code works, and I am able to see the flag on the homepage, but if I navigare to other pages, I can't see the image. The html somehow renders the image if I am only browsing my index page.

Comment: That's unlikely (unless your browser's broken). The path in your question's code is relative, meaning it would work on every page of the site. What you're describing suggests you have a static path instead, e.g. src="themes/mytheme/images/flag.jpg"

Comment: I don't understand the second sentences but I can tell you the path is not acting as if it was relative. That's why I asked. It should work for all pages but right now only the main `/` page shows me the image but not if I go to `/about-us` or `/contact` or just any other page

Comment: Then check the image source is correct, i.e. has a proceeding `/`. If it has, and it works from one path on the same domain, but not another, the problem is with the browser. Or possibly the web server, but that would be such a custom configuration that you're bound to know about it

Comment: So, I copied to defunct image path while I opened `http://dev.drupal/resources/blogs` path and this is the image path `http://dev.drupal/ressources/themes/mytheme/images/flag.jpg` for some reason the `/blogs` suffix is left out.

Comment: Because `/` is relative to the _domain_. It'll need to start with `/resources/themes/` if that's where the image is

Comment: But `/resources` is just a page like `/about` .. I don't understand this.. If I tell drupal to fetch the image from `/themes/mytheme/images/flag.jpg` it should always start looking the image from `/themes/...` no matter whether I am on index `/` page or `/about` page. But that is not the case here

Comment: Correct. The only time it wouldn't is if you omitted the leading slash, or the browser wasn't doing what it should